# How to Add Required in JHTML Select Box in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

How to Add JHTML Select box Required Attribute. My code is Given Below.

```
$result = TrueMatrimonyHelperSelect::getDateList('date', '', '');   
echo JHtml::_('select.genericlist', $result, 'date', 'text');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have passing arguments in the JHtml::_('select.genericlist');

> Syntax:
>
> ```
> genericlist($arr, $name, $attribs=null, $key= 'value', $text= 'text', $selected=NULL, $idtag=false, $translate=false);
> ```

[click on joomla docs JHTMLSelect/genericlist](https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JHTMLSelect/genericlist)

You can pass **$attribs**

```
Solution:
    $attribs = "class='required' ";
echo JHtml::_('select.genericlist', $result,'date',$attribs,'text');
```